# Dotfuscator 5 CE - renaming exclusion by signature

Tags: obfuscation, dotfuscator

I'm running dotfuscator 5 from the command line using a config file. This works ok, more or less, except for one new requirement that's just come about.

I have a class with a small number (less than half a dozen) void methods that need to be excluded from renaming (for a roundabout system of calling reflected methods by name; don't ask...)

Their signature is (names changed to protect the innocent) `void Method(System.Xml.XmlNode xnode, ref System.String str)`.

My question is two-fold:

- How do I express a ref parameter in dotfuscator configuration syntax?
- Why doesn't using the signature of the method quoted in the Map file work?

The map file contains the element `<signature>void(System.Xml.XmlNode, string&amp;)</signature>` when these methods are renamed. I would expect therefore to be able to specify in the config file:

```
<type name="ParentClass" excludetype="false">
<method signature="void(System.Xml.XmlNode, string&amp;)"/>
</type>
```

This doesn't work. The output from the command line utility claims that the config file is invalid.

If I include the syntax `name=".*" regex="true"`, **all** the methods in the type are excluded. I don't want that. I understand why this is - the rules are ORed together - but the utility forces me to use options I don't want by rejecting config files that specify my actual requirements.

What gives?

I feel - because I am beginning to get annoyed with this - that I should point out that I have found the Dotfuscator documentation to be....not very good.

Comment: Downvoters: Please explain why you downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The config file is invalid because the method node has no "name".

If you're **just** trying to exclude one particular method, you can use the UI to actually click the checkbox next to that method in the Renaming -> Excludes treeview on the left, which will generate the correct XML for you. If you decide to go this route, delete your existing `<type>` node first.

If you want it to match any method in ParentClass with that signature (even if there's only one), the xml should be (substitute in the correct value for `<Namespace>`):

```
 <type name="<Namespace>.ParentClass" excludetype="false">
    <method name=".*" regex="true" signature="void(System.Xml.XmlNode, string&amp;)"/>
 </type>
```

With the rule created, you can use the UI to navigate to the Rename -> Exclude tab, right click the method node in the Custom Rules treeview on the right and click Preview.  It should highlight the method you're looking for.  Here's a screenshot of what it should look like in the UI when Preview is clicked:  http://files.preemptive.com/Support/CustomRuleRefParam.png

Comment: Thanks. I did try including the `name` attribute, but as I mentioned, I found that this matched every method in the class. The [manual](http://www.preemptive.com/images/stories/dotfuscator_documentation/Dotfuscator/webframe.html) says *"Rules are logically OR-ed together."*. This matches my experience - a method with a `name` of [anything] OR with a `signature` of [blah] will be matched. Is this not the case?

Comment: A given rule (represented by the `type` node in your case) is a full description of what's required to match that rule (the requirements are AND-ed together). For example `name=".*" signature="void(int, string&)"` means "match any method with the following signature".

If you have multiple rules (you've only described one rule here), **those** are logically OR-ed together (meaning if any one rule causes something to be excluded, then that element is definitely excluded even if other rules didn't exclude it)

Comment: Ah. I see. It's possible I was mistaken when I inspected the result of running Dotfuscator on my assembly (using the map file and ILDASM). Visual Studio has been giving me the runaround just lately so I'll try performing the process again carefully.

Comment: Well, I've attempted the process again, using the method I had been previously which according to your answer, was correct all along. I can confirm that it did not work. Examining the assembly in ILDASM, I can see that all the methods in the class, including the ones that match the <method> rule, have been renamed. I've tried using the UI to compare its syntax against my own, and they are identical. Every other rule in the config file seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried opening the config file with the GUI and checking that "Preview" option to see what it's matching?  That might help sort it out.  If you have a repro you can package up and email, send it to me at my SO username @preemptive.com.